# How to restrict containment property of sortable to any div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

The containment property limits the drag of the elements to the edges of the browser window. Which give me scroll bar lengthy with empty space.I have a list within a div `drop_down_list`now for making sortable I wrote following code:

```
  $('.drop_down_list').sortable({                        // make drop down sortable.
         axis: "y",
         placeholder: ".drop_down_list_placeholder",
         forcePlaceholderSize: true,
         containment: ".drop_down_list",
         scrollSpeed: 3000
   });
```

but when I am dragging my `li` element outside the `div` than scroll bar is still increasing and I am getting white space in my `div`, after dropping element everything is OK. I want to restrict my scroll bar length within my `div`, how can I do that ?
jsfiddle link for the problem- http://jsfiddle.net/mqnrD/24/

Comment: can you represent your issue in a jsfiddle so that we can have a better look at your problem

Comment: I added jsfiddle link, now please have a look in problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jsfiddle, adding "scroll: false" to the sortable callback should fix this.